# Mujtahid vs Mujahid

Tags: jihad, arabic-translation

I know that Mujtahid and Mujahid both have as root word ج-ه-د J-H-D. But what is the difference Mujtahid and Mujahid between them both in:

1. The arabic language
2. Islamic framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a root word in Arabic is matched to root word فـ عـ ل "Fa'l"

> جـ هـ د
>
> فـ عـ ل

Now let's take the first word Mujtahid مـ جـ تـ هـ د and match it with Mufta'l

> مـ **جـ** تـ **هـ** **د**
>
> مـ **فـ** تـ **عـ** **ل**

Mufta'l is a noun describing the one who do the action so it will mean "who exert effort"

the second word Mujahed مـ جـ ا هـ د will match the word conjugation of Mfa'el

> مـ **جـ** ا **هـ** **د**
>
> مـ **فـ** ا **عـ** **ل**

Mufa'l is also a  noun describing the one who is doing the action it will mean "Who is exerting effort"

the difference in language that the first word Mujtahid can describe who exert the effort now and maybe stop later, however the second word Mujahid can describe who is continuously exerting effort.